# How many different right-handed Power Swords are there on the sprues of the Space Marines?

Tags: warhammer-40k, miniatures

I am looking to make a group of Vanguard Veterans who wield Power Swords, but since they are not on the sprue I will have to pilfer them from other boxed sets. But since the GW website is rather incomplete regardings sprues, I cannot really tell where I can find these things.

Note that I am looking for right-handed Power Swords for models in Power Armor, either consisting of one part or the hand/weapon + weapon arm combination.

Comment: not sure how many you need, or how much you will spend trying to get them from associated sprues, but [shapeways](http://www.shapeways.com/model/264626/power-sword-mrk1-small.html?modelId=264626&materialId=5) has a number of designers that make bits and pieces for models.

Comment: Well, I was going to buy Tactical, Assault and Devastator Marines, Sternguard and Vanguard Veterans anyway (two of each for these), so I'm just wondering. About ten would be nice, but would that mean I had to buy a total of six boxes combined of the first three to get a total of ten? And how about Scouts? I want to use the Relic Blades for other purposes.

Comment: I can't truly comment because I have not bought those boxes, however I get the feeling that if the power sword is an option for those troops then each models sprue will probably have one included. I would bank however on at least half the models in the box. At least with the old Dark Eldar that is how it was I.E. chain cannons.

Comment: I've done a bit more research, and the only ones I can find right-handed power weapons on is on the Assault Marines (one sword, one axe) and the Vanguard Veterans one (one sword, one axe). Plenty of others (Tactical Marines, Command Squad, Commander) have them too, but they are right-handed. But are those really the only ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I have done some more research, asked around and I have come to the following conclusion regarding the Power Weapons on the sprues of the regular Space Marines. Some are entire arms, others are just hands. Likewise some weapons have one bladed edge, the others two.

Tactical Marines Squad

- 1 left-handed double-bladed Power Sword, hand.

Assault Marines Squad

- 1 left-handed double-bladed Power Sword, arm.
- 1 left-handed single-bladed Power Axe, arm.

(Note: on the older sprues these are both right-handed)

Devastator Marines Squad

- 1 left-handed double-bladed Power Sword, hand.
- 1 left-handed single-bladed Power Axe, hand.

(Note: this is on the sprues of the new boxed set)

Vanguard Veterans

- 1 right-handed single-bladed Power Sword, hand.
- 1 right-handed single-bladed Power Axe, hand.

Command Squad

- 1 left-handed double-bladed Power Sword, arm. Note that this one is intended for the Company Champion, not for the Sergeant as is usual.

Space Marine Commander

- 1 left-handed double-bladed Power Sword, arm.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to buy your bits individually. There are tons of options out there, one example is [Hoard O Bits](https://hoardobits.com/cgi-bin/hob/shop.pl?cat1=sword&view=02172017-2-10) though you might want to dig around a bit, this was a fairly quick search. You can also often find bit sellers on eBay.